# Textinput doesn't react on spacebar after text replace

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have the issue, which described in a title and here is example

In jsp file I have the script

```
 <script>
  function checkNoSpaces(id){
    return function (){
      var value=$('#'+id).val();
       if(value){ 
        $('#'+id).val("");
         //Or document.getElementById(id).value=''; and " " or `` . Doesn't matter
        }
}
}
</script>
```

Now if my field like

```
....
<div class... onClick="return {valid: {userDefined: checkNoSpaces('NameId')}}">
<html:text name="dataBean" 
property="data.name" styleId="NameId"/>
```

And when I input spaces into textInput and press Enter, every spaces get deleted as it should be like. But after that I can't input any spaces, but other other symbols can.

No, I can input it but page doesn't show that while I don't input any symbol.

It could looks like when I pressed 5 times on spacebar 
    "" 
And when I add some letter it would be
     "     A"

Comment: Looks like you are using this method for validation, a lot of validation libraries works like this "They won't validate fields until first submit, but once you submit, they start validating on every change". From the behavior you mentioned, I think that is what is happening here, but cannot confirm without the knowledge which validation framework you are using.

Comment: You are correct in a part of that. I try to validate that field wouldn't have something like "   " or "    Name" . But there is no any framework here, only my own work around. And `validate` it is too my object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not appropriate answer,but anyway, that code doesn't work in Edge even with compatibility mode ,but in Opera and IE it works fine.